# How can I convert componentDidUpdate to the useEffect react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I converted my class-based component to a functional component and thought I had the conversion of the `componentDidUpdate` method correct, but my linter is complaining, so I could use some clarification on what I'm getting wrong.

This is my `componentDidUpdate` function on a class-based component:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (
    prevProps.hasUnlockBeenClicked !== this.props.hasUnlockBeenClicked &&
    this.props.hasUnlockBeenClicked &&
    !this.props.startAt
  ) {
    this.saveInitialSession();
  }
}

saveInitialSession = () => {
  const { setSessionProperties, agentId, customerId, customerName } = this.props;
  setSessionProperties({
    agentId,
    customerId,
    customerName,
    startAt: moment().format(),
  });
}
```

This is what I'm attempting to change it to using `useEffect()` on a functional component:

```
const saveInitialSession = () => {
  setSessionProperties({
    agentId,
    customerId,
    customerName,
    startAt: moment().format(),
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (hasUnlockBeenClicked && !startAt) {
    saveInitialSession();
  }
}, [hasUnlockBeenClicked]);
```

Eslint is telling me that the dependency array needs to include `startAt` and `saveInitialSession`, which doesn't make any sense to me. I only want it to run if the `hasUnlockBeenClicked` has been changed.

Comment: Are you using VS Code?

Comment: Yes I sure am!!

Comment: after the if-block in your `useEffect` add the following:   `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: Isn’t that eslint rule there for a reason? Can you tell me why I would just want to turn it off?

Comment: Looks like valid warning. You should add `startAt` and `saveInitialSession` in the dependency array. Check for explanation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies). Search for the example expelling about `ProductPage` and how `fetchProduct` `productId`  should go into depedencies.

Comment: You can see more :https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920

Comment: Panther, so if startAt changes, won’t it run the function? I only want the anonymous function to run if has UnlockBeenClicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-do-i-fix-missing-dependency-in-react-hook-useeffect/55854902#55854902

Comment: is `setSessionProperties` a setter from `useState()`? If yes, I have workaround for you on this thing.

Comment: `setSessionProperties` is a redux action creator